# emacs font-lock-mode for JavaScript: would like to highlight 'self' just like 'this'

Tags: javascript, emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

Because I often have to preserve `this` from getting overwritten in closures, I like to do: `var self = this;` at the top of my constructors. I'd like to subsequently highlight `self` exactly how and when `this` is currently highlighted. However after studying the emacs documentation, websites, and examples here, and adapting the examples, it's not working.  I'm evaluating this expression:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'javascript-mode
        '(("self" . 'font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

both in my `.emacs` file and in the javascript buffer, and also toggling `font-lock-mode` to force a refresh. I've tried variations with the confusing `"\\<self\\>"` syntax but I'm clearly throwing darts because that also fails. I see many variations of `font-lock-add-keywords` but being only an Emacs power user and not a developer, it seems byzantine.

As context, this is GNU Emacs 24.5.1 running as a native Mac OS X 10.11.5 App, not in terminal.

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com may be a better place for questions like this, although since your question is specific to using it as an IDE, SO may be OK as well.

Comment: Using self is almost never necessary these days. Arrow functions will usually get the job doing done. You may want to take this opportunity to experiment with a non-self programming style.

Comment: Very selfless of you to point that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting how posting here improves my own troubleshooting. :-)

JavaScript mode is actually `js-mode`, not `javascript-mode`. I don't have the patience to figure out why there's two, probably historical. So this worked, fixing two niceties (word boundary, and correct face) along the way:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook (lambda() 
          (font-lock-add-keywords 'js-mode '(("\\<self\\>" . 'font-lock-constant-face)))))
```

Comment: `javascript-mode` is an alias for `js-mode`, but other names do have to be correct (`js-mode-hook`, etc), so it does cause confusion from time to time...